# how to change aspect ratio of the PANEL (grey area) in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, aspect-ratio

Hi I'm plotting a pie chart and putting the names on there. And the text was cropped outside the panel (grey area).

Is there a way to change the aspect ratio of the panel?

I tried `theme(aspect.ratio=1.5)`, but this changes the pie chart to an ellipse. I want the pie chart not change, and want the panel be wider. And I tried adjust the size of the picture, but this doesn't change the panel (grey area).

Any help's appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
source('PieChart.R')

df = data.frame('Name' = c('long long name one', 'long long name two', 
                           'long long name three', 'long name long four'),
                'Count' = c(10, 20, 30, 40))


png(width=1000, height=600, file='/Users/Yuji/OneDrive/Data/TownState/pie.png')

PieChart(df, 'Name', 'Count')

dev.off()
```

PieChart.R

```
PieChart = function (Data1, Name1, Value1){

        position = cumsum(Data1[[Value1]])-0.5*Data1[[Value1]]

        ggplot(data = Data1, aes_string(x=1, y=Value1, fill=Name1)) +

                geom_bar(stat="identity") +
                coord_polar(theta ='y') +
                theme(axis.ticks=element_blank(),
                      axis.title=element_blank(),
                      axis.text.y=element_blank(),
                      axis.text.x=element_text(colour='black'),
                      legend.position='none',
                      # panel.background = element_blank(),
                      panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
                      panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
                      panel.border = element_blank()#,
                      # aspect.ratio=1.5
                ) +

                scale_y_continuous(breaks=position, labels=Data1[[Name1]])
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure it's possible: the aspect ratio needs to be unity for the pie to be circular. As a workaround, you could turn off clipping and plot on top of a grey background.

```
b = ggplotGrob(p + theme(plot.background=element_rect(fill=NA,colour=NA)))
b$layout$clip[b$layout$name=="panel"] = "off"
grid.draw(grobTree(rectGrob(gp=gpar(fill="grey92")), b))
```

Alternatively, you could manually edit the widths/heights of the gtable. First step is to replace the null units of the panel to "snpc", which will remain square, then change the margins to "null" units to expand as much as possible.

```
library(grid)
library(gtable)

p2 <- p + theme(plot.background=element_rect(fill="grey92"))

g <- ggplotGrob(p2)
g$layout$clip[g$layout$name=="panel"] <- "off"

g$respect <- FALSE

grid.newpage()
g$widths[[4]] <- unit(1,"snpc")
g$heights[[3]] <- unit(1,"snpc")
g$widths[c(1,5)] <- rep(list(unit(1,"null")), 2)
g$heights[c(1,6)] <- rep(list(unit(1,"null")), 2)
grid.draw(g)
```

[image]

Comment: I've been looking for a solution to a very similar problem for a long time.